# Sub-class not able to access the protected method of super-class when the reference is of type super-class

Tags: java, access-modifiers

Parent class

```
package p1;

public class A {
    protected void display() {
        System.out.println("Displayed");
    }
}
```

Child class (in another package)

```
package p2;

import p1.A;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.display();
    }
}
```

In the child class, if I write `B a = new B()`, it works fine and displays "Displayed".

But, the above piece of code in child class where `A a = new B()` is written, it throws compile time error as `'display()' has protected access in 'p1.A'`

I am confused with the protected access modifier now as how it works when the reference type is of parent?

Comment: You are in static method, not in B's method... Test with `foo()` in B ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant Language Specification paragraph:

> If the access is by a qualified name Q.Id or a method reference expression Q :: Id (§15.13), where Q is an ExpressionName, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of the expression Q is S or a subclass of S.

([6.6.2.1. Access to a protected Member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2))

In your case, `Q` is `a`, and `S` is `B`. Since the type of `Q` is not a subclass of `B` the access is not permitted.

For the explanation on why this restriction was introduced, see [Checking Access to Protected Members
in the Java Virtual Machine](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/87dd/b97e608b16089bdf5647f1de6ee6a02f9139.pdf) (search for *Requirements on Protected Members*)

> The motivation
>   behind the restriction on protected access is to prevent almost arbitrary access
>   to protected members of objects [Yel02]. Suppose that m is a protected, nonstatic
>   field declared in c. Without the restriction, any class x could read the
>   content of the field m of any object of class c, using the following trick: define a
>   subclass s of c (the trick works only if c is not final, hence the “almost” adverb
>   above); declare a method in s that takes an object of class c as argument and
>   returns the content of its m field; and have x call this method. The restriction
>   on protected access prevents this situation, because s can access the field only
>   if the class o of the object satisfies o ≤ s

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in a comment, you can do this:

```
package p2;

import p1.A;

public class B extends A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        a.foo();
    }

    public void foo() {
        display(); // works
        super.display(); // same, but more wordy
        A a = (A)this;
        a.display(); // NOT working !!!
    }

    public void bar(A a) {
        a.display(); // NOT working !!!
    }
}
```

`display()`, can be called from subclass (static method is not member method) or in same package like this

```
package p1;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        a.display();
    }

}
```

hm, those

```
a.display(); // NOT working !!!
```

are something not really clear to me, see [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164563/discussion-between-vijayinani-and-ramanlfc)

Comment: but even if I am in static method, I am calling display method on a reference. Then how does B a = new B() works!

Comment: I know it's a bit confusing, **static** method is not **member** method and this is important. The table [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) is for **members**...

Answer (score 1):

`A a = new B();` doesn't work because the reference type of `a` is `A` and `A` doesn't expose `display()` to another package.

take this example:

```
public void method(A a){ // defined in some class in a different package
   a.display(); // can't be called from different package as reference type is `A`
}
```

the compiler here has no way to know whether you'll assign a `A` or a subtype of `A` and hence it bails out.

It will be easier to understand if you forget your example for a second and just focus on the method i've created, notice that i'm saying it's in a class defined in a different package. now ask yourself can i call `display()` on `A` from a different package, obviously not it's a protected method.

Comment: What? Makes no sense... You can call `display()` on all sub-classes of A.

Comment: @Betlista yes in a subclass but not by creating a variable with reference  type of base type

Comment: Of course you can, see my example with C... You just have to have visibility in place you are calling it.

Comment: @Betlista the reference type of `a` in your example is `B` which compiler knows inherits from `A`, hence it works

Comment: Check again, there is no way, that `a` in `A a = new A();` holds instance of B... (class C).

Comment: @Betlista your `C` class is in the same package as `A`,that's the only reason it works

Comment: @Ramanlfc but that is how protected is designed right? child can access the protected members of parent. How is reference type making a difference here?

Comment: @vijayinani yes child can access bcoz it accesses it through `this` , but when you create a variable the type of that variable is the key for the compiler to determine whether it can access a protected member or not

Comment: @Ramanlfc so should I understand that protected can only work if my reference is of child type and for parent type reference the method has to be always public. Not able to digest it completely!

Comment: @vijayinani i've updated the answer, please read the last part and think carefully

Comment: yes read, but display is protected right? and B is subclass of A. So display should be accessible. Dosent matter the object type is of B or A as I have not overridden display in B, it will always call the display from A.

Comment: @vijayinani instead for `A a = new B();` imagine for a second that you had `A a = returnAorSubtypeOfA()`, the method will run at run time and assign some object to `a`, since the compiler doesn't know what that object will be it just looks at the compile time type of `a` and then see that `display()` is `protected` and hence will come to the realization that `display()` can't be called from a different package

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164563/discussion-between-vijayinani-and-ramanlfc).

Answer (score 0):

**Protected methods can only be accessible through inheritance in subclasses outside the package**

**display** will be accessible to every subclass AND every class in the same package.

**display** will be accessible to every class in the same package (not available in children class if there are in a different package)

A a = new B(); will not work because the reference type of a is A and A will not exposing display() to another package.

**Below code will work:**

```
package p2;

import p1.A;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B a = new B();
        a.demo();
    }

    public void demo(){
        display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think from the link: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/access-modifiers.html important statement is

The protected access modifier provides the same access as the default access modifier, with the addition that **subclasses can access protected methods and member variables (fields) of the superclass.**

Here, subclass means subclass reference type only. For parent reference type, the only option left is public.

It is kind of unstated hidden rule. Even the IDEs are suggesting to change it to public to access via parent's reference. Weird!